# How to get string between 2 strings

Tags: javascript

I have a String for example this String:

```
bigString = "<div dir=\"rtl\" style=\"text-align: right\"><ul><li><span>רשאי, רק כאשר הרכב העוקף הוא רכב משא.</span></li><li><span>רשאי, רק בדרך שאינה עירונית.</span></li><li><span id=\"correctAnswer1759\">רשאי.</span></li><li><span>רשאי, אם באוטובוס אין נוסעים.</span></li></ul><div style=\"padding-top: 4px;\"><span><button type=\"button\" onclick=\"var correctAnswer=document.getElementById('correctAnswer1759');correctAnswer.style.background='yellow'\">הצג תשובה נכונה</button></span><br/><span style=\"float: left;\">| «D» | </span></div></div>"
```

I want to get each one of those Strings.
For that I decided to save in array the first String between `<li><span>HERE</span></li>`
and then remove the tags that was covering it from the big String and to do it 3 times until each one of those Strings are in array.

I could do it with Java but there is another problem with Java so I decided to do it in JavaScript.

In Java I could use this function to get the first String:

```
arr[j] = StringUtils.substringBetween(bigString,"<li><span>","</span></li>");
```

And then replace the first `<li><span> </span></li>` tags with those functions:

```
bigString = bigString.replaceFirst("<li><span>","<null>");
bigString = bigString.replaceFirst("</span></li>","<null>");
```

Now I can't find proper functions to replace the Java ones.

```
var bigString = data.records[0].description4;
var end = "</span></li>";
var start = "<li><span>";
var strings = []; bigString.split(end).forEach(s => {index = s.indexOf(start);
    if (index >= 0) {strings.push(s.substring(index + 3)); }});   
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    console.log(strings[i]);
}
```

Result: https://prnt.sc/w1wugv

The result I need:
רשאי, רק כאשר הרכב העוקף הוא רכב משא.
רשאי, רק בדרך שאינה עירונית.
רשאי, אם באוטובוס אין נוסעים.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definetly not the cleanest one, but I would propose a solution like this to fetch all strings into an array:

```
function getMiddleStrings(bigString, begin, end) {
  strings = [];
  bigString.split(end).forEach(s => {
    index = s.indexOf(begin);
    if (index >= 0) {
        strings.push(s.substring(index + begin.length));
    }
  });
  return strings;
}
```

The array `strings` contains all the substrings then.

By calling `getMiddleStrings(bigString, "<li><span>", "</span></li>")` you are then basically splitting the String at every `</span></li>` tag and then removing all the stuff before and including all the `<li><span>` tags.

Comment: It dosent work on my code. I don't know why (I changed the bigString so you can understand because it's not in english take a look at the edit please and tell me why it dosen't wok now.

Answer (score 1):

This code encloses the desired elements with a unique string. Then it splits the text on this unique string and if the required tags are present it takes the text content

```js
var bigString = '<div dir="rtl" style="text-align: right"><ul><li><span>רשאי, רק כאשר הרכב העוקף הוא רכב משא.</span></li><li><span>רשאי, רק בדרך שאינה עירונית.</span></li><li><span id="correctAnswer1759">רשאי.</span></li><li><span>רשאי, אם באוטובוס אין נוסעים.</span></li></ul><div style="padding-top: 4px;"><span><button type="button" onclick="var correctAnswer=document.getElementById("correctAnswer1759");correctAnswer.style.background="yellow"">הצג תשובה נכונה</button></span><br/><span style="float: left;">| «D» | </span></div></div>';

var res = [];

var splStr = bigString.replace(/<li><span>/gi, ',,#*&,,<li><span>')
    .replace(/<\/span><\/li>/gi, '</span></li>,,#*&,,')
    .split(",,#*&,,");

for (let i = 0; i < splStr.length; i++) {
    if (splStr[i].indexOf('<li><span>') > -1 && splStr[i].indexOf('</span></li>') > -1) {
        res.push(splStr[i].replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, ""));
    }
}

console.log(res);
```

Comment: for the first 2 sentence it's working just fine but for the last one it contain other chars

Comment: I made a change to the code. It is very difficult for me to know if I have achieved the right result because I do not know the language but I hope it works for you now

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to get result -

```js
var bigString = '<div dir="rtl" style="text-align: right"><ul><li><span>רשאי, רק כאשר הרכב העוקף הוא רכב משא.</span></li><li><span>רשאי, רק בדרך שאינה עירונית.</span></li><li><span id="correctAnswer1759">רשאי.</span></li><li><span>רשאי, אם באוטובוס אין נוסעים.</span></li></ul><div style="padding-top: 4px;"><span><button type="button" onclick="var correctAnswer=document.getElementById("correctAnswer1759");correctAnswer.style.background="yellow"">הצג תשובה נכונה</button></span><br/><span style="float: left;">| «D» | </span></div></div>';

var matches = bigString.matchAll(new RegExp(/<li><span>(.*?)<\/span><\/li>/g));

var groups = Array.from(matches); 

var result = groups.map((m) => m[1]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got an Solution for you that is written in C#, but im sure you could translate it into JS 'cause it's not using any C# specific methods.

Take a look at my code:

```
int openTagStart = fulltext.IndexOf("<", pos);
int openTagEnd = fulltext.IndexOf(">", pos);

int closedTagStart;
int closedTagEnd;

int textStartPos;

string textInTags;

tag = fulltext.Substring(openTagStart + 1, openTagEnd - (openTagStart + 1));
textStartPos = openTagEnd + 1;

closedTagStart = fulltext.IndexOf("</" + tag + ">", textStartPos);
closedTagEnd = closedTagStart + 2 + tag.Length;

textInTags = fulltext.Substring(textStartPos, closedTagStart - (textStartPos));
```

You have to iterate it twice because of your nested Tags. But its pretty universal because you don't have to care about the kind of tags.

EDIT:
Or you could try get an XML/HTML parser for JS, this might be the most elegant way to handle this.